# Question about polynomials with maxima and minima.

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Determine (up to a constant multiplier) the polynomial with a maximum at $(-1,1)$, a minimum $(1,-1)$ and no other critical points.

The only thing I can think of is coming up with an equation with roots $1$ and $-1$ and then integrating it but I don't think that will work.

Comment: Sounds like you need a cubic.

Comment: Why don't you see if it works? Try drawing a picture of what the shape must look like.

Comment: One problem is, there isn't just one polynomial that satisfies the conditions. The one provided by Baloown is the one of smallest degree, but if you choose $P'(x) = k(x^2 - 1)^2$, you get another solution, and others for higher powers of $x^2 -1$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint :** try with your idea : you know that the derivative of your polynomial is $k(x-1)(x+1)=k(x^2-1).$ Integrate this and get that your polynomial is $k(\frac{1}{3}x^3-x)+c.$ Then use your informations about the values of your polynomial at $-1$ and $1$ to find $k$ and $c$ and finally get $P=\frac{1}{2}X^3-\frac{3}{2}X.$

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial of degree $n=3$ in general has exactly $2$ extreme points so let's use a cubic polynomial $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ with $a \ne 0$. Obviously the derivative of this function is $f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c$.

We now need to find values of $(a,b,c,d)$ such that \begin{align}f(-1) &= 1,&f(1) &= -1, & f'(-1) &= 0, & f'(1) &= 0.\end{align}
Since there are $4$ variables and $4$ equations, there is a unique solution.